# iOS Removing Object From Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am loading an array of items from a plist. A user can select any item and add it to a new array of items which is shown on screen.

I am doing this but a user can also delete a player from any row. My problem is when a user deletes the object it shuffles the list up. Where as I want to keep that row blank.

My deletion code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *user_id = [prefs objectForKey:@"user_id"];
    NSString *fixture_id = [prefs objectForKey:@"fixture_id"];

    // Get path to documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);


    [self.usersSelectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (self.usersSelectionArray == nil) {

        // disable swipe to delete?
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([paths count] > 0)
    {
        // Path to save array data
        NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",user_id, fixture_id]];

        // Write array
        [self.usersSelectionArray writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];
    }

    // If blank array delete the file as not required
    if (self.usersSelectionArray.count == 0) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", user_id, fixture_id]];

        NSError *error;
        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])
        {
            //TODO: Handle/Log error
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It also checks if the count is 0 and deletes the plist, re-creates on load if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove an object from your data array, but keep an empty cell for it in the table?

In that case I recommend replacing the removed object with an `NSNull` instance.

```
[myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
```

You can then check if the object for a cell is `NSNull` and return an empty cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method.

```
id object = // get the correct object from your data array, depending on the index
BOOL isEmpty = [object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
if (isEmpty) {
    // return empty table cell
else {
    // return a normal cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked :D, what would I go around doing if I wanted to re-insert an object at that index?

Comment: Replace the `NSNull` object with your object and reload the table. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Basically if they delete row 2 and then tap back on row 2 and select a player, it just adds the item to bottom of array with keeping the NULL object.

Comment: I don't know how you're adding new players. You'd have to make sure that you replace the correct NSNull in that case.

Comment: I think my problem is the delete and replace row is not actually saving to the plist for some strange reason.

Comment: Well, do you write the array to disk after changing it? By the way, you can't write NSNull to plist files. So if you have to write the array to a plist, maybe you should use an empty NSData instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[self.usersSelectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, try `[self.usersSelectionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNull null]];`. That will keep the row but it will contain practically nothing